# GraphQL query throws 'QueryKeyMaker cannot handle circular query structures' with simple React Native setup

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-apollo, graphql-js

I spun up a new expo app with `expo init`, added basic GraphQL dependencies, and was greeted with this fun, unshakable error:

`QueryKeyMaker cannot handle circular query structures`

whenever any `<Query />` component is mounted. I've published a minimal [example app](https://expo.io/@slowcodetochina/test) that crashes with the same error when pointed at a public graphql endpoint. The source code for the example is [here](https://github.com/sammccord/QueryKeyMaker-issue-repo).

It's been happening on my OnePlus 6 with Android 9 Pie, and cannot test with iOS (am on Linux), but would love to know if the same error throws. Would appreciate any insight, as Google has completely failed me.

Comment: Hey @slowcode, we are getting the same issue. If you turn remote debugging on, it strangely works. Out of interest do are you using a package.lock / yarn.lock file?

Comment: Weird! Probably not the best production strategy. The package-lock is checked in to the repo above, https://github.com/sammccord/QueryKeyMaker-issue-repo/blob/master/package-lock.json. I filed an issue with react-apollo but now am not sure if that was even the right place considering remote debugging affects the outcome.

Comment: Linked to issue on react-apollo for others with this bug:
https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2442#issuecomment-425927367